# CakePHP 3.2 Cascade Delete

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've just upgraded my `CakePHP` to version 3.2. However, I am experiencing a problem.

I would like to do a cascade delete for a single Schoolassessments record from the Schoolassessments table. In the Schoolassessments table, I've set my (id and student_id) as PK in the database.

```
$selectedAssessment = $Schoolassessments->find()->where(['id' => $assessmentId, $this->typeField =>'2AAA-XXXX'])->first();
$Schoolassessments->delete($selectedAssessment);
```

This is the Schoolassessments table.

```
$this->hasMany('SchoolassessmentsScores', [ 
    'className' =>'SchoolassessmentsScores', 
    'conditions' => [
        'Schoolassessments.id = SchoolassessmentsScores.assessment_id'
    ],
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'dependent' => true,
    'joinType'  => 'INNER'
]);
```

This is the SchoolassessmentsScores table.

```
$this->belongsTo('Schoolassessments', [ 
    'className' =>'Schoolassessments', 
    'conditions' => [
        'Schoolassessments.id = SchoolassessmentsScores.assessment_id'
    ],
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'joinType'  => 'INNER'
]);
```

After the the Schoolassessments record has been deleted. The SchoolassessmentsScores associated records should be deleted as well.

However, the `debugkit` is showing the following error.

```
Warning (2): array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements [CORE/src/ORM/Association/DependentDeleteTrait.php, line 44]
```

```
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE/src/ORM/Association/DependentDeleteTrait.php, line 53]
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Please show some context, ie the configuration of the involed table classes and associations. The primary key and foreign key setup of your actual database tables may also be important.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question.